# How to check value exists in table or not?

Tags: mysql, exists

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO votes (post_id, user_id, value, date_time)
    SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?
    FROM $table_name t
    WHERE {if t.id exists $id} limit 1
```

How can I write this `{if t.title exists 'anythin'}` in MySQL ?

---

**EDIT:** Actually I want to check `post` is exists in the `Posts` table before inserting a vote for that post.

Comment: Its not very clear what you're attempted to filter by...if t.title exists at all, t.title = 'anything', or 'anything' is some param fed into your query? Can you explain in a brief paragraph?

Comment: Yes, you should post more details. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to select 'where' data exists, try `WHERE t.title IS NOT NULL`.

If it is to complete a conditional statement which inserts 'anything' if there is any data, then try `(if t.title is not null, 'anything', null)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $Posts_table_name WHERE Id = 'YourPostId');
```

Edit:
You wrote: " *Actually I want to check post is exists in the Posts table before inserting a vote for that post.*"

Best way to do this is to set post_id as foreign key so, if the id doesn't exist the insert query will not have effects